# Process products outside app ( Play Billing )

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Can I process subscriptions  and non-consumable products after purchase. I want process it outside my app?

Such as acknowledge of products or consume some product?

Because sometimes problems will happened inside app like lost connection or user not enter to the app even I can process purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not allow you to do it in most cases

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en